# My #include dependencies seem to be preventing me from using a class

Tags: c++, dependencies, header-files

I am trying to use a function from another class but my dependencies seem to be stopping me.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "gesture.hpp"
#include "statemachine.hpp"

Gesture g;
StateMachine sm(g);
```

**gesture.hpp**

```
#include "hand.hpp"
```

**statemachine.hpp**

```
#include "gesture.hpp"

StateMachine(Gesture&);
Gesture *g;
```

---

**What I am trying to accomplish:**
I am trying to use a function from the `StateMachine sm` that I have declared. This function would be called inside a function in `gesture.cpp` and I would be giving my `Gesture g` class a pointer to `StateMachine sm`. (I would do this after I declare  `sm` in main) I am able to `#include "statemachine.hpp"` in my `gesture.cpp` file but I want to move it to `gesture.hpp` so I can have it as a pointer that is stored as a variable in that class.

So when I do 
**gesture.hpp**

```
#include "hand.hpp"
#include "statemachine.hpp"
```

I get the error `'Gesture' does not name a type` and `expected ')' before '&' token StateMachine(Gesture&);`

Can anyone figure out what is going on? I can't move my function to `gesture.cpp` because it uses an array that is stored in my `statemachine.hpp`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Purpose of Header guards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979384/purpose-of-header-guards)

Comment: Hard to say since you're not giving enough info to be definitive, but my guess is you need a forward declaration.  Look it up.

Comment: The problem is probably related to a circular dependency. If `A.h requires B.h` and `B.h` requires `A.h` then you got a problem. To solve it you must use forward declarations, so that `A.h` includes `B.h`, `B.h` doesn't include `A.h` but forward declares the types that are defined in `A.h`. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816698/avoiding-circular-dependencies-of-header-files

Comment: Actually, I'm taking note of the fact that `Gesture` is nowhere declared or defined in your stated content of `gesture.hpp`.  This would explain your problem quite well.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, I have declared ```Gesture();``` in gesture.hpp and the problem actually stems from the fact that I didn't know what forward declaration was, or that it was an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide the details so i will post my guess here.
When the precompiler analyze "gesture.hpp", it will unroll it to something like this:

```
codes in hand.hpp
StateMachine(Gesture&);
Gesture *g;
```

the file "gesture.hpp" is not unrolled in statemachine.hpp because i think you had provided some protections against circular dependency. so the compiler don't know what Gesture is.

To solve the compiling error, you can put a forward declaration of Gesture to statemachine.hpp, like this:

```
class Gesture;
StateMachine(Gesture&);
Gesture *g;
```